# MS Outlook : Method to import reoccurring events (i.e. birthday list)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, import, data-transfer, events

Starting-point is an Excel-List containing the names and dates of birth for a lot of person. Those should be imported to Outlook as event series (yearly reoccurring event).

Outlooks CSV-import doesn't supports reoccurring events.
The best solution would allow to import the list even again, when someone is added or removed and then events are updated.

I had a look to import the list to a new, separate calendar and show them in list-view but wasn't able to modify all imported events to become yearly reoccurring.

Maybe csv-import is not the best solution?

Does anyone has an idea or eventually a working solution?

Comment: Consider a converter that can do recurring events:  https://www.csv-to-ics.com/

Comment: Is Outlook able to import ICS to a specific calendar ?

Comment: You would need to look through that product description. Normally an ICS file can be imported to a specific calendar.

Comment: Just for clarity, Excel can convert data to an ICS file on a one time basis. It is the recurring part that needs the converter app I referenced here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint to the ICS-Format. Yes, it is the reoccurring wich makes the trouble using the CSV. Going to test ICS (iCal) now.

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to try the ics file, according to my experience, you could also try to work with a macro, for your reference: [How to Batch Import Birthdays from Excel Worksheet to Outlook Calendar](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/batch-import-birthdays-excel-worksheet-outlook-calendar/)

Hope that would also work for you.

Comment: Whether it work for you? If your issue has been resolved, it's recommended to mark the helpful post or share your solution.